# How do I join these tables to show associated username?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have three table Profile,Messages and Login Which are related as shown below in picture and I want to show username for Message sender And Message receiver(two last row in messages table).  this Query shows only Username associated to the receiver id What can I do?

```
SELECT     Login.Username, 
           Messages.Subject, 
           Messages.Text,
           Messages.Status, 
           Messages.Id, 
           Messages.Senduserid, 
           Messages.Recuserid
FROM     Login INNER JOIN  Messages 
        ON  Login.Profileid =  Messages.Recuserid
```

Relationship

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to join on to the Login table twice.  Once for each user that you want to pull out.  (Their are alternatives, but this is typically the easiest and most common).

To do that, you need to give each reference to the Login table a different Alias...

```
SELECT
  Message.*,
  sender.Username,
  receiver.Username
FROM
  Messages
INNER JOIN
  Login            AS sender
    ON sender.Profileid = Messages.Senduserid
INNER JOIN
  Login            AS receiver
    ON receiver.Profileid = Messages.Recuserid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this by joining the Login table twice

```
SELECT     a.Username as ReceivedUsername,
           b.Username as SentUsername,
           c.Subject, 
           c.Text,
           c.Status, 
           c.Id, 
           c.Senduserid, 
           c.Recuserid
FROM     Login a, Login b, Messages c
        where  c.Recuserid = a.Profileid and c.Senduserid = b.Profileid
```

Comment: @Dems runs away screaming at yet more people using `,` notation here on SO.  We're all doomed!!!  *[Besides, does that even work? Using `,` notation with `ON` instead of `WHERE`?]*

Comment: @Dems Why so serious?...

fixed the ON thing.. forgot to remove it :P

Comment: Sorry, that was *meant* to be a *comedic* way of saying that I personally agree that `JOIN` should always be used in preference to `,` :)

Comment: @Dems I understood you buddy. I was just trying to be sarcastic!! http://qkme.me/35et2u